# Setting up Outlok Email to AD (Active Directory) Group Members in Power Shell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, outlook

I am working on a PowerShell script to do the following: pull all the email addresses from an existing Active Directory (AD) group and then populate a new, open Outlook email with those addresses for notification of group members.

Here are the pieces I have got in place and both work"

1) Grab the email addresses:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity "My Group" | Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq 'user'} | Get-ADUser 
-Properties EmailAddress | where {$_.EmailAddress -ne $null} | select EmailAddress
```

2) Start a new email in Outlook, ready to send (Found this snippet on the web)

```
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$mail.Subject = "<subject>"
$mail.Body = "<body>"
$mail.save()

$inspector = $mail.GetInspector
$inspector.Display()
```

So the piece I am missing is how to pipe the output from 1) into the email.Recipients field of the new email? Who can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to send an item to each address returned by the first part then something like this should work.

```
$Group = Get-ADGroup "My Group"
$Members = Get-ADGroupMember $Group | Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq 'user'}
ForEach($Member in $Members){
$CurrentDN = $Member.distinguishedName
$CurrentMember = Get-ADUser $CurrentDN -Properties mail| where {$_.mail -ne $null}
$EmailTo=$EmailTo + $CurrentMember.mail + "; "}
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$mail.To = $EmailTo
$mail.Subject = "<subject>"
$mail.Body = "<body>"
$mail.save()
$inspector = $mail.GetInspector
$inspector.Display()
```

Comment: I had tried the ForEach loop before based on a lot of posts on the web... but all this does is run through all the email addresses in my To: field and then finally display the last email like this: @{EmailAddress=somebody@somewhere.com}. What I want is all the address in the same email - I guess in comma-delimited format.

Comment: Edited the script per your notes.

Comment: That's it exactly, Trey. Thanks a bunch. This will be a huge time saver. After learning Python and starting with C#, I need to study PS!!!

Comment: No problem.  Do keep in mind that if you run this from ISE the '$EmailTo' variable will keep compounding if you run it multiple times so you may need to recycle it with an '$EmailTo=$Null'

Answer (score 0):

Set the MailItem.To/CC/BCC properties to a ";" separated list of addresses. Or call MailItem.Recipients.Add for each address.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I came up with the above by mostly trial and error and don't know PS very well. So how to I get the multiline output of email addresses into Mail.to ?